# Metrisability of WOT on unit ball of bounded operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, weak-topology

I am given a metric $d$ on the closed unit ball $S$ of $B(H)$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$, and I am to prove that it induces the weak operator topology (WOT) on $B(H)$. To this end, I am allegedly to prove that a net $\{f_\lambda\}_{\lambda ∈ \Lambda}$ in $S$ converges in the WOT to some $f ∈ S$ iff $d(f_\lambda, f) → 0$. Can anyone give a thorough detailed explanation of why this is indeed sufficient? (I am a little rusty on my general metric topology.)

Comment: Maybe this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149108/two-topologies-coincide-if-they-have-the-same-convergent-nets

Comment: Somewhat, though I'm not sure I would classify that answer as 'thorough and detailed' :p

Comment: A set $F$ is closed iff for every $x\in F$ there is a net $x_i\in F$ that converges to $x$. Thus, if two topologies have the same convergent nets, then they have the same closed sets.